# unity screen space overlay advantages

Tags: unity-game-engine

all.I have a question after learning unity ugui.

There is three mode of the render mode of unity canvas.

Screen Space - Overlay mode keeps the UI can be drawn over any other graphics.
But if I want to show any particles or effects in the front of UI.It becomes very difficult.And the UI elements can't be affected by Post Processing.

Can anyone tell me this mode there is any other special advantage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The special advantage is that you don't need to specify a camera for the canvas to render to. This way you can put that canvas in a separate scene and `SceneManager.LoadAdditive()` it into a gameplay scene as needed.

For more information, you can check my old answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47281987/1645830).

Comment: Thank you very much, you tell me some new knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main advantage is that it allows the developer to do minimal changes to the canvas itself for it to perform like it should,i.e it will always project the UI elements in front of the GameObjects present in the scene.

Answer (score -3):

you have to set the canvas to World Space.

here is the link to the documentation.
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UIWorldSpace.html